# html scrape using requests and lxml produces <Element x at location> instead of the text located at that node

Tags: python, html, xpath, python-requests, lxml

I'm creating a Python program, using lxml and requests to scrape text from a website. However, when I navigate to the correct node, my code produces an element label instead of the text that's located at that node.

```
# import packages
from lxml import html
import requests

# initialize program with URL
ficUrl = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10847788/'

# pull metadata
page = requests.get(ficUrl)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="profile_top"]/b')
print(title)
```

When I inspect the page, what should be located at that node is text, "Goldstein". However, my program prints `[<Element b at 0x11171e548>]`. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `title[0].text` ???

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I needed to add a `/text()` tag to the end of the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10847788/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
data = soup.select_one('#profile_top .xcontrast_txt').text
print(data)
```